# How to create a PPA that just contains links to other PPAs?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

So that I just have to maintain one PPA on maybe Launchpad and have all the packages I like.

**Update:** Nifty workarounds are welcome, too ;)

**Update:** I'm running a server here at home. So if there is a solution where I can set up my own private repo, that would be totally fine.

Comment: Do you want to compile all your packages and put them in a PPA or just have an easy way to install packages from other PPAs? If it is the latter, why don't you just maintain a list of PPAs in a file, and a list of packages in a file?

Comment: It is the latter, and I don't do it the way you proposed because **I** have to maintain it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an apt proxy daemon on the server, something like apt-cacher-ng or apt-mirror for example (sorry, no more info, haven't tested it, but [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20setup%20apt%20cache) seems to have a wealth of information about these packages).

Comment: I think [apt-mirror](http://apt-mirror.sourceforge.net/) will solve my problem although I'd find it better if launchpad provided such a feature. Congratulations on the bounty, you need it more than Rinzwind and your answer was closer to what I wanted ;)

Comment: Thanks although I'm not hungry for rep, I just hope my answer helped. :) I wouldn't recommend creating a separate PPA just to "link" (copy) other packages, since it defeats the purpose of a personal package archive (in my opinion).

Answer (score 4):

You can add PPA's in a script and excecute the script when you need to re-install these PPA's (for instance because of re-installing your system).

Example...

Execute from command line:

```
touch install_ppa
chmod 775 install_ppa
gedit install_ppa
```

and copy/paste your PPAs into the file. Rearrange your code to be efficient. Example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tiheum/equinox
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-equinox faenza-icon-theme equinox-theme
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
nautilus -q
```

Put the file on a partition you do not format during installing or on a stick and you can execute the file thus adding these PPA's.
You can also add downloads with wget in it to install tar files etc etc.

<sub>**Commands have not been tested**</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer but although I'm a programmer myself I'm also a lazy bum ... I like nicely integrated things. And your solution is more like a workaround but unfortunatly not a nifty one ... no offense, sorry. - I could upload it to Ubuntu One but there is no version control in case I edit the file on various machines. And when I use a VCS I have to do so many things manually. [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/) would be a nice tool but it is still in early development. :(

Comment: who says you need to be a programmer? You find the ppa's you need and add them to a script. That's not programming. That is copy/pasting :=D And I bet you will not get another answer as good as this (yes that's a challenge to all ;) )

Comment: I just wanted to say that I'm fully capable of implementing your solution. But it still lacks automatization (deployment on all of my PCs, execution). I'll fiddle around a bit with SparkleShare. It has now some source package for linux. Maybe it works better now.

Comment: these things you left in comments should have been inside your question.